# A .clone is not working properly nor is it returning array of names

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code is supposed to have three input boxes and when I click "add set", it should clone the three input boxes. When I click "Get Company Names" it should return an array of company names, being all of the values from the boxes.

As it stands, "add set" does not work and I do not understand why.
Another problem is that, "get company names" returns an object rather than a value like
the .val would suggest.

```
`alert($("#workExperienceBox").find("input[id=companyName1]").val(""));`
```

Also, in the fiddle, you will see the code that I am using to duplicate boxes. `extraWorkEpxerience` is a div and `workExperience` is the first div inside of that div.

```
var workExperience = $("#workExperienceBox").clone();
    $("#extraWorkExperience").html(workExperience);
```

The fiddle is exactly where I am currently at.
please help!

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tubbstravis/tmakdo1x/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Id has to be unique, So I had made the id's that you have used as classes. Also the other problem is that you are using `html()` instead of `append()`, as a result that could make the entire html content of that container to be replaced.

```
var getNames = function(num) {
  alert($(".workExperienceBox").find(".companyName1").map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get());
}

var addWorkPlace = function() {
  var workExperience = $(".workExperienceBox").clone();
  $("#extraWorkExperience").append(workExperience);
}
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tmakdo1x/6/)